# Using a class as the type for STL map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, c++builder

I'm using Embarcadero C++ Builder XE, Windows 7, 32 bit. I have problem to compile code using a class as the type for STL map.
In my simple test-example the class declaration is following:

```
#include <map>
class TMyClass
{
private:    // User declarations
 int cVal1;
 int cVal2;

public:
    TMyClass& __fastcall operator = ( TMyClass& aMyClassObj);

public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TMyClass( void);
    __fastcall TMyClass( int aVal1, int aVal2);

    __fastcall TMyClass( const TMyClass& aMyClassObj);  // copy constructor 1
    __fastcall TMyClass(       TMyClass& aMyClassObj);     // copy constructor 2
    __fastcall ~TMyClass( );
};
```

The class is used in the map:

```
typedef std::map< int, TMyClass>  TMyMap;
```

I'm trying to insert an object into to map:

```
TMyMap  sMyMap;
TMyClass     sMyClassObj( 10, 10);
aMyMap[ 1] = sMyClassObj;
```

The last line gives the compilation error:

```
[BCC32 Error] xtree(29): E2285 Could not find a match for 'pair<const int,TMyClass>::pair(const pair<const int,TMyClass>)'
  Full parser context
    xtree(28): decision to instantiate:  _Tree_nod<_Tmap_traits<int,TMyClass,less<int>,allocator<pair<const int,TMyClass> >,0> >::_Node::_Node(_Tree_nod<_Tmap_traits<int,TMyClass,less<int>,allocator<pair<const int,TMyClass> >,0> >::_Node *,_Tree_nod<_Tmap_traits<int,TMyClass,less<int>,allocator<pair<const int,TMyClass> >,0> >::_Node *,_Tree_nod<_Tmap_traits<int,TMyClass,less<int>,allocator<pair<const int,TMyClass> >,0> >::_Node *,const pair<const int,TMyClass> &,char)
    --- Resetting parser context for instantiation...
    U_TestKompilacji.cpp(10): #include U_TestKompilacji.h
    U_TestKompilacji.h(5): #include C:\Programms\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0\include\boost_1_39\boost\tr1\tr1\map
    map(20): #include C:\Programms\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0\Quickrep505C\../include/dinkumware/map
    map(5): #include c:\Programms\embarcadero\rad studio\8.0\include\dinkumware\xtree
    xtree(8): namespace std
    xtree(13): class _Tree_nod<_Traits>
    xtree(25): class _Tree_nod<_Traits>::_Node
    xtree(28): parsing:  _Tree_nod<_Tmap_traits<int,TMyClass,less<int>,allocator<pair<const int,TMyClass> >,0> >::_Node::_Node(_Tree_nod<_Tmap_traits<int,TMyClass,less<int>,allocator<pair<const int,TMyClass> >,0> >::_Node *,_Tree_nod<_Tmap_traits<int,TMyClass,less<int>,allocator<pair<const int,TMyClass> >,0> >::_Node *,_Tree_nod<_Tmap_traits<int,TMyClass,less<int>,allocator<pair<const int,TMyClass> >,0> >::_Node *,const pair<const int,TMyClass> &,char)
```

I've been trying to find a solution for many days. There was no such problem in Borland C++ Builder 6.0, which I've used before.
Are there some kind of requirements for the class to be used as a value in a map?

Comment: The assignment operator should take a `const` reference, and you should almost certainly get rid of that weird "copy constructor 2". I don't know whether that's the cause of the problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few minor problems

1. The default constructor should be declared `TMyClass()` (without `void`). This is only a style problem (the empty parenthesis/void distinction for function declarations is for C, not C++).
2. Why the copy constructor is different for `const` or not `TMyClass&`?
3. Why all that `__fastcall` noise? This is the first thing I'd remove to see if it's a problem.

To be able to put an element in a map as the value the class must be assignable, copy-constructible and also default constructible (`operator[]` needs to be able to default-construct an element) and all seems ok in this case.

Unfortunately C++ compilers are known for producing almost useless error messages when you enter the template realm.

Comment: The solution was to remove the "copy constructor 2".

Comment: @user3455001: the copy constructor accepting a non-const reference is VERY weird, but I'm surprised it's a showstopper when creating a map using such a class as value. Indeed with other compilers this is not a problem at all (e.g. g++, clang)